# API interceptor for real time scanning

Tags: architecture, interceptor, api-design

I am designing an interceptor to capture APIs request and response in real time to identify sensitive information. 
The requirement is to stay as an independent component and intercepts every APIs request and response.

[image]

please find the attached architecture design with interceptor.
I need expert suggestion to effectively implement interceptor.

Comment: That's a very open-ended description of the problem. What are the requirements exactly? What is the stack you're using? Should this interceptor be an application interceptor or a separate proxy stack? What is your "real-time" SLA?

Comment: @trein, here is my answers.  What are the requirements exactly? my goal is to get a copy of every API response before that has been sent out to it client. What is the stack you're using?  interceptor needs to work independently irrespective of existing stack. Should this interceptor be an application interceptor or a separate proxy stack? separate proxy  What is your "real-time" SLA? there is no SLA limit. All I need is to get a copy of API response for analytics purpose.

Comment: @Arun your API/service backend is 1 single application or a mesh or services? Also if its a many services/micro-services are they on single language stack or polyglot?

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi It is 1 single services. Assume that service could be implemented using any language such as Spring Boot or ASP.NET.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this question is off-topic ("too broad" and "opinion-soliciting") - there are many ways to implement such a tool (many languages, many approaches, etc). As written, this is essentially a set of requirements, with no specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches you can use.

> 1. Side-car: Create a reusable library which, has nothing but an interceptor or filter(for java) or actionfilter for .net platform. Once added as dependency and instantiated by your application, All request and response can be accessed here and pushed to a broker. And one of your workers can read from broker.
> 2. API Proxy/Gateway: A lightweight api gateway like kong can be used as a proxy and your application will remain intact. You will be able to log all HTTP headers and payload to a broker. Advantage here is, even if you have more than 1 applications the solution will remain same, and is agnostic to backend application language or lifecycle.

Comment: 1st choice is not an option as it requires code change in API and creates dependency.  I am little concerned about 2nd choice because it may affect API SLAs when it goes down in worst case scenario.  I am looking at pyshark or something similar kind of solution to get a copy of API payload from a port (let say) 443, decrypt it using shared decryption key and publish it to broker. It would not affect API SLAs even it goes down. It is an idea I am trying it now.

Comment: You can try envoy[ https://www.envoyproxy.io] as well. Though i would act as the data plane for your application.